# Rails HTML templating

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, templates

So I am working on a regular rails3 application, and I have outsourced my templates to a remote designer.

I received templates as html files, and I am trying to insert some logic, the same way that [enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive) does it in clojure.

I am still doing back and forth work with the designer, so translating to erb is not an option.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

If you generate your HTML's dynamically and there is subsequent modification work on such generated results. Then the only option is to merge the update diffs. It can't be automated and must be manually driven. To ease this process I suggest to run diff on previously current generated HTMLs and the one you got from the designer. Then seeing just diffs you have to manually incorporate them back to your logic.

Better solution would be to encourage your designer to setup rails and modify *.html.erb or whatever you use. You'd probably want to prepare fixtures for him analogous to unit test fixtures so the generated HTML's will have non trivial expansion.